# How to retrieve the returned type (runtime type) of a method declaration prior to call the proceed() method in an @Around advice

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Having the following hierarchy:

```
Accessor
  AccessorSub01
  AccessorSub02
```

Consider them like a simple set of domain classes

For an `@Around` advice I need know the **runtime type** for the *return type* **but** *prior to call* the `proceed()` method.

Through this link:

- [When using spring aop:around, how can I get return type of the pointcut method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092800/when-using-spring-aoparound-how-can-i-get-return-type-of-the-pointcut-method)

I wrote the following:

```
@Around("AccessorPointcut.methodLevel05(methodLevel)")
public Object aroundMethodLevel05(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MethodLevel methodLevel) {
    String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    System.out.printf("[AccessorAspect - aroundMethodLevel05] " +
                      "MethodName: %s - Arguments: %s - @MethodLevel: %s %n",
                       methodName, Arrays.asList(args), methodLevel.value());

    Signature signature =  pjp.getSignature();
    Class<?> returnType = ((MethodSignature) signature).getReturnType();
    System.out.printf("[AccessorAspect - aroundMethodLevel05] Class<?> [ReturnType CanonicalName]: %s%n", 
                       returnType.getCanonicalName());

    //TODO: implement a cache control

    Object object = null;
    try {
        object = pjp.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.printf("%s%n", e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.printf("[AccessorAspect - aroundMethodLevel05] " +
                      "MethodName: %s - Arguments: %s - @MethodLevel: %s - Returns: %s %n",
                       methodName, Arrays.asList(args), methodLevel.value(), object);
    return object;
}
```

Considering this interface:

```
public interface AccessorService {

    Accessor something01();
    Accessor something02();

}
```

The `@Around` advice code works fine if the following is used:

```
@Override
@MethodLevel("something01")
public AccessorSub01 something01() {
    return new AccessorSub01("Something 01");
}

@Override
@MethodLevel("something02")
public AccessorSub02 something02() {
    return new AccessorSub02("Something 02");
}
```

The return type in the method declaration and the return type is the same subclass. For the former thanks to Polymorphism it is possible. Therefore in the `@Around` advice is printed either `AccessorSub01` or `AccessorSub02` according the case

But having the following:

```
@Override
@MethodLevel("something01")
public Accessor something01() {
    return new AccessorSub01("Something 01");
}

@Override
@MethodLevel("something02")
public Accessor something02() {
    return new AccessorSub02("Something 02");
}
```

The return type in the method declaration is the super class, same as the interface declaration, but the return type is a subclass.
The `@Around` advice prints always `Accessor` and not neither `AccessorSub01` nor `AccessorSub02`.

*If is possible* - How to accomplish this goal?, I need either `AccessorSub01` or `AccessorSub02` according the case.

Of course

```
    Signature signature =  pjp.getSignature();
    Class<?> returnType = ((MethodSignature) signature).getReturnType();
```

Works for class/declaration and not for runtime

**Remember** I need this data prior to call the `proceed()` method - so there is no *object* in that point of time yet. This request is need it to implement a kind of cache control.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that either AspectJ or you would need to have a magical crystal globe by which to predict the future or maybe a time machine. How can you possibly know the type of an object in advance which will only be created later in a method which has not been called yet? This is not even an AspectJ problem, it is a logical problem per se.

Your question also is an example for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) (just like your previous one I just commented on), i.e. you describe **how** you imagine to solve a problem technically instead of saying **what** you actually want to achieve. The way your question is posed presently, I can only speculate, and my guess is that your application design is flawed in some way. For example, maybe you should rather intercept constructor calls than method calls in order to cater to your caching needs or use factories instead of `new Something()` directly, but this is is speculation, like I said. You did not share enough information for me to suggest a more concrete solution.